# How to skip SSL certificate verification with karate?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to turn off SSL certificate verification through karate. For now I'm getting error:

```
       13:27:14.668 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, http call failed after 133 milliseconds for URL: https://VRNV02AS04294.int.carlsonwagonlit.com:8443/admin/property/filters/APFilter/true
       13:27:14.668 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed:
```

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please do this:

```
* configure ssl = true
```

Read the docs for more: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure

EDIT: for those landing here in the future (and on Karate version < 1.0), I recently realized that if the above fails, it is most likely that you have added Karate to a Java Maven (or Gradle) project that has a different version of the Apache HTTP Client libraries in scope. And what happens is that the JAR conflict causes some SSL related classes to fail to load.

There are 2 solutions:

1. use [`karate-jersey`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#maven) instead of `karate-apache`
2. force the version of the Apache dependencies like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.version}</version>
     </dependency>
```

The value of `apache.version` depends on what your project needs and what Karate depends on, and in most cases, using the [latest possible version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient) would work.

EDIT 2023: Note that from [Karate 1.2.0 onwards](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.2.0-Upgrade-Guide) using the Karate fat-jar can solve similar issues. Refer to the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-core-fat-jar

Comment: It is not working. First of all  " * configure ssl = true" gives me error "NoSuchMethod" so configured like following "And eval function(){return karate.configure('ssl', true);}". But I still getting SSL error

Comment: @mirchik please follow these instructions, all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I solve this problem. One of the dependencies (Apache http) is using a deprecated method for ssl. So I just upgraded a version of the dependency, and it is working now!

Comment: @mirchik Thanks! Adding Apache httpclient dependency in the project solved the issue.

Comment: for me it's not working even I have added Apache httpclient
getting this exception 
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

Comment: @Az.MaYo latest versions of karate embed apache and all dependencies. follow this process please (if you can) else there is nothing anyone can do to help you: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas I am facing issue because I am using karate Junit5 with Spring boot web starter, any hints to resolve this please

Comment: @Az.MaYo if you are mixing this in a big pom it can be hard. the only remaining hints I have are here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/database/README.md - unless I can replicate it I can't help you. all the best

Comment: It was my bad it's working fine thanks @PeterThomas

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar situation and to resolve this I added

```
karate.configure('ssl', true);
```

in the karate-config.js file to let Karate know to skip SSL certification verification globally.

Also I had to add a http-core dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

First turn off SSL certificate verification in karate:

```
* configure ssl = true
```

AND add below dependency in your pom.xml. I got resolved my issue by doing so:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me below approach worked:

**Defining keystore in karate-config.js file:**

```
// get system property keystore
var keystore = karate.properties['keystore'];
if (!keystore) {
    keystore = 'C:/Program Files/keystore/certificateName.pfx';
}

// get system property keystorepwd
var keystorepwd = karate.properties['keystorepwd'];
if (!keystorepwd) {
    keystorepwd = '00000';
}
```

**Defining below line in background in .feature file:**

```
configure ssl = { keyStore: #("file:"+keystore), keyStorePassword: #(keystorepwd), 
keyStoreType: 'pkcs12' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using * configure ssl=true - it solved the problem in my local
But my script is failing on jenkins - giving connection timeout errors.

can anyone pls let me know how can i execute my karate script on jenkins.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34546280)