# How to resolve javax.net.ssl.SSLException in the quickstart example?

Tags: java, karate

For some reason I just can't get the quickstart example running. My assumption is that it is related to corporate proxy. Here are my steps:

1. Create new project using the Maven archetype (as described in the documentation).
2. Run the tests (without any adjustments first) and getting the following results:

```
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.net.UnknownHostException: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, http call failed after 648 milliseconds for url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
[pool-1-thread-2] ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.net.UnknownHostException: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, http call failed after 564 milliseconds for url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - classpath:examples/users/users.feature:9
When method get
http call failed after 648 milliseconds for url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
classpath:examples/users/users.feature:9
[pool-1-thread-2] ERROR com.intuit.karate - classpath:examples/users/users.feature:36
When method post
http call failed after 564 milliseconds for url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
classpath:examples/users/users.feature:36
---------------------------------------------------------
feature: classpath:examples/users/users.feature
scenarios:  2 | passed:  0 | failed:  2 | time: 1.3194
---------------------------------------------------------
```

3. Making the following adjustments to `karate-config.js`:

```
function fn() {
  // ...
  var config = {
    // ...
    proxy: {uri: 'https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:1234', username: 'my_username', password: 'my_password'},
  }
  // ...
  karate.configure('ssl', true);
  karate.configure('proxy', config.proxy);
  return config;
}
```

4. Run the tests again and getting the following results:

```
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?, http call failed after 278 milliseconds for url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
[pool-1-thread-2] ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?, http call failed after 100 milliseconds for url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - classpath:examples/users/users.feature:9
When method get
http call failed after 278 milliseconds for url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
classpath:examples/users/users.feature:9
[pool-1-thread-2] ERROR com.intuit.karate - classpath:examples/users/users.feature:36
When method post
http call failed after 100 milliseconds for url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
classpath:examples/users/users.feature:36
---------------------------------------------------------
feature: classpath:examples/users/users.feature
scenarios:  2 | passed:  0 | failed:  2 | time: 0.5533
---------------------------------------------------------
```

5. Adding `httpclient`, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52396293/7385255) older SO answer. Unfortunately, still the same results as in point 4) above.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: sounds like that domain is simply blocked where you are.

Answer (score 1):

Merge the certificate from your corporate proxy into the default truststore and provide it to your program.
Your corporate proxy likely uses an selfsigned certificate which is not in the truststore and therefore cannot be used to connect via HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

Try any other example:

```
Feature: simple requests

Scenario: simple post
* url 'https://httpbin.org'
* param foo = 'bar'
* path 'anything'
* request { foo: 'bar' }
* method post
* match response contains { json: { foo: 'bar' } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately this does also not work, same error:

`[main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?, http call failed after 199 milliseconds for url: https://httpbin.org/anything?foo=bar`

`[main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - src/test/java/examples/users/simple.feature:8`

Could it be related to corporate certificate, as user `krankkk` mentioned above?

Comment: @Tobias I have no idea. if you replicate following this process, we will look at it (but I think you can't, so you are on your own): https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue